# Normalizing Keywords Bug

Tags: search, string

The `StringHelper::normalizeKeywords()` doesn't work as I expected.

When I normalize `überblick` it leads to the expected result:

```
StringHelper::normalizeKeywords('überblick') -> ueberblick
```

But when I normalize `ÜBERBLICK` I expect it also to be `ueberblick` but it actually returns `überblick`.

It could be fixed by adding the missing ASCII mappings (e.g. 196 => 'Ae') to the `StringHelper::getAsciiCharMap()` method or converting the string to lowercase before replacing the characters in `StringHelper::normalizeKeywords()` on lines 358 - 362:

```
-> switch these two lines:

// Remove punctuation and diacritics
$str = strtr($str, static::_getCharMap());

// Normalize to lowercase
$str = StringHelper::toLowerCase($str);
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug... I'd recommend reporting this directly to support@craftcms.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bug, and is probably worth reporting to P&T.

However, it's very difficult (if not impossible) for them to account for every potential ASCII character mapping for every possible language. For that reason, there is a [customAsciiCharMappings](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#customAsciiCharMappings) config setting, which you can use as a workaround.

Comment: Ok I'll report it. For now I just lowercase the string before passing it to the normalize method to get the correct result.